# there is no android:layout_below in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put a recyclerview below my LinearLayout but there was no android:layout_below option for the recyclerview!
then i tried to put my recyclerview into a LinearLayout and set layout_below for the layout but there was no layout_below for linearlayout either!

I'm sorry i'm not good at english but anyway ... here is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tablo.mirshekari.customers.StoreFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/store_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="lasjdbkajbd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/store_name" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic2w"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="lasjdbkajbd"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/store_textposition" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/address_white"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post your code here. don't use an external link (especially one that requires login). that way users can still read your question if that link goes down.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo sorry i edited it

Comment: You should give `ConstraintLayout` a try. It's the default for all the templates now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, `layout_below` is only available for `RelativeLayout`. See [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) and [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html).

This means, you must put your views into RelativeLayout to use that attribute.

**UPDATE**

Yep, you are putting your views to a `FrameLayout`. Consider changing it to `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation or using `RelativeLayout` with `layout_below` for the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Linear layout does *not contain* android:*layout_below* option. 
So, you can use **relative layout** in place of **linear layout** to use **android:layout_below** option .